# i18next saying key missed always

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node.js. I want to work with internationalization. I am trying using i18next. I have written this code:

```
i18n.init({
  lng: 'en',
  debug: true,
  load: ['en', 'ar'],
  fallbackLng: 'en',
  backend: {
    "loadPath": path.join(__dirname,"locale/en/translation.json")
  },
  getAsync:false
}, (err, t) => {
  console.log("this is key value :"+(t("key")));
  return t;
});
```

And in my `en/translation.json` file I have this contents:

```
{
  key:"hello anil"
}
```

When I run the program I get this error: `i18next::translator: missingKey en translation key key`

What went wrong? Please help me out.

Comment: no updates on this one? running through the same issue :/

Answer (score 0):

Check your debug log.

I found the `loadPath` is not what I thought, after fixing the path it works.

The reason is my js file is in build directory, so the path becomes `build/locales/en.json` not `/locales/en.json`.

the error message,

```
[Error: ENOENT, open '/opt/www/build/locales/en.json']
   errno: 34,
   code: 'ENOENT',
   path: '/opt/www/build/locales/en.json' } ]
```

this is my fixed config,

```
backend: {
    loadPath: 'locales/' + '{{lng}}.json',
},
```